# Скачивание музыки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, поиск-библиотек, музыка

Пытаюсь сделать бота для поиска и скачиванию музыки в телеграме с помощью python, telebot. Как бы не пытался найти библеотеку предоставляющию такую возможность(поиск музыки по названию, певцу и возможности скачивания, ну ещё отправку в тг) - не нашёл. Надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: Поставьте метку [tag:поиск-библиотек] и почитайте её описание заодно

Comment: Изменил, спасибо

Comment: Берете requests (или что -то более безопасное), логинитесь в Telegram'e, отправляетесь на страницу с музыкой и там смотрите, есть ли нужная, берете на нее ссылку, и, с помощью того же `requests` забираете музыку. Если вам ссылок достаточно - берите `BeautifulSoup`, если вам нужно взаимодействовать с сайтом - `Selenium`